# CSS increase padding by number

Tags: html, css

I just wanted to know whether there is a way to increase the padding of an object by a number. For example

```
#mydiv{
   padding: 50px; /*padding of one div*/
}

div {
   padding: +50px; /*basically increase the padding of all divs by 50*/
 }
```

So the resulting padding on `#mydiv` should become `100%`.

will `calc()` be useful?

I know that there are other JavaScript alternatives, but I want to do it in plain CSS only, if possible.

Comment: please don't show the backticks

Comment: Did you think about using a CSS preprocessor like 'LESS' (http://lesscss.org/) or 'SASS' (http://sass-lang.com/)?

Comment: _“will calc() be useful?”_ – no, it won’t. The operands need to be length values, you can not use it to “look up” values specified elsewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do it the way you want like getting the padding of another element/class/... and add some value. But what you can do is declaring a variable and use this one:

```
:root {
  --base-padding: 50px;
}

div{
  padding: calc(var(--base-padding) + 50px);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

#mydiv{
  padding: var(--base-padding);
  background-color: green;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/268zzwqc/1/

It is not the same, but should work fine for your case.